# Jest expected mock not called (redux component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, redux-thunk

In React, I am testing that a button click inside a child component causes a function to be called in the parent component (onDeleteClick), via event bubbling.
For this test, I am using `mount`, as shallow will not allow us to trigger a function in a child component.

`onDeleteClick`, the function I am trying to check whether it was called or not, is a class property which in this case, is an arrow function.

I am mocking the onDeleteClick function, and passing it into my component via a Redux `Provider` when starting the test.

The problem I am having is that at the end of the test, when I perform a check to see if the mocked function was called, it returns 0.

`expect(onDeleteClick.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);`

If I put a console.log within onDeleteClick(), it's outputted during the test, so I know that the function is in fact being called.

I have researched this quite a bit and so far haven't gotten anything to work.
Some suggestions were to spy on my mocked function, and then call forceUpdate on the wrapper, but this didn't yield any positive results.

For this, I am using `Jest` with `Enzyme`.

Reference Code:

Parent.js

```
    import { deleteAccount } from '../../actions/profileActions';
    import ChildComponent from '../common/ChildComponent';

    class ParentComponent extends Component {

      onDeleteClick = () => {
        console.log('onDeleteClick was executed during this test!')
        this.props.deleteAccount();
      }

      render() {
        let dashboardContent;

        dashboardContent = (
           <div>
              <ChildComponent onDelete={this.onDeleteClick} />
           </div>
        );

        return (
          <div>
             {dashboardContent}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    // propTypes and mapStateToProps removed from this post

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      { deleteAccount }
    )(ParentComponent);
```

__tests__/ParentComponent.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { mount } from 'enzyme';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';    
    import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
    import ParentComponent from '../ParentComponent';
    import thunk from "redux-thunk";    
    const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

    const deleteAccount = jest.fn();

    const props = {
      deleteAccount
    }

    const randomTestState = {
    // some initial state, not important
    };

    const randomTestStore = mockStore(randomTestState);

    describe('<ParentComponent />', () => {
      it(`mounts the ParentComponent component and, when ChildComponent sends onDelete, then deleteAccount function is called once`, () => {

        const wrapper = mount(
          <Provider store={randomTestStore} props={props}>
            <Router >
              <ParentComponent />
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        );

        // Here, I grab an element in ChildComponent and simulate a click using Enzyme, then the event bubbles up, and deleteAccount() is called in the parent component. 

        // the console.log we expect to see from onDeleteClick is logged to console.
        // the call does not seem to have registered though and the expect returns falsy

        expect(deleteAccount.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
      })

    });
```

Could the problem be that I am wrapping the component in a Provider?
I have a hunch, but I couldn't find any concrete examples of tests which use a Provider to wrap their component when running integration testing

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I needed to change my main ParentComponent file from

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
```

to this:

```
extend class ParentComponent extends Component {
```

and then in my test file, import the component like so:

```
import { ParentComponent } from '../ParentComponent'; // non-default export should be wrapped in braces
```

and then update my test so that I assign the wrapper variable like so:

```
const wrapper = mount(<ParentComponent {...props} />);
```

This then allowed the test to pass

```
expect(deleteAccount.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

It was recommended [here in the Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components)